# Gridster.js not displaying properly on page load

Tags: jquery, asp.net

I'm using the [following Gridster](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AzvJ9.png) library to create a dynamic grid layout and wondering why my grids are not displaying properly on page load. I've added some background colors to actually show the elements.

This is what they look like when i load my page. 
[image]

This is what they look like after i either drag or resize a tile.
[image]

Here is the Script that runs on the page.

```
<script>
    function pageLoad() {
        gridster = $(".gridster ul").gridster({
            widget_margins: [10, 10],
            widget_base_dimensions: [140, 140],
            resize: {
                enabled: true,
            }

        }).data('gridster');
    }
</script>
```

Apart from that, everything else is stock standard. Is there something within my Script tag that initialises the Grid properly once Drag/Resize is triggered, that I could also have on page load?

Comment: Looks like I had a 'float' further up in the styling hierarchy on the page, which filtered down into my ul and li elements.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was that a 'float' style-attribute within a DIV tag existed within the Grid markup that affected the positioning of the elements. This was removed giving the example in the 2nd screenshot above on page load.